# Does AWS S3 object support POSIX Hardlinks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I am working on project where I need to upload a file-system directory, which contains both hard-links and soft-links, to a given AWS S3 bucket. I am wondering if there is support for hardlinks (bunch of empty objects pointing to an object or if AWS has internal mapping which returns same object for multiple GET calls for haldlinked object)?

The reason why this is important is because say I've 1GB file which has 100 hard-links, I don't want to be billed for 100 * 1GB storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not support POSIX filesystem semantics at all.  S3 is an object store, not a filesystem, and as such it does not support either hard or soft links.

However, the APIs are all open and documented, so you do have the option of writing your own abstraction layer.